# Why does associating belongsTo in Sequelize give me this error?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm stuck with this problem for quite some time now and I don't know what's wrong with my code I'm trying to associate one table to another but only half of it works any help would be greatly appreciated.

models/companies.js

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');
const Users = require('./users');

const Companies = sequelize.define(
    'companies',
    {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        image_url: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: true
        },
        created_at: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: Date.now()
        },
        updated_at: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: Date.now()
        }
    },
    {
        //Rewrite default behavior of sequelize
        timestamps: false,
        paranoid: true,
        underscored: true
    }
);

Companies.hasMany(Users);
Users.belongsTo(Companies);


Companies.sync();

module.exports = Companies;
```

models/users.js

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');

const Users = sequelize.define(
    'users',
    {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(60)
        },
        role: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
            allowNull: false
        },
        image_url: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            unique: true
        },
        batch: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(3)
        },
        major: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(10)
        },
        company_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        created_at: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: Date.now()
        },
        updated_at: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: Date.now()
        }
    },
    {
        //Rewrite default behavior of sequelize
        timestamps: false,
        paranoid: true,
        underscored: true
    }
);

Users.sync();

module.exports = Users;
```

Then after I try to run this code below

```
const Companies = require('./database/models/companies');
const Users = require('./database/models/Users');

//Relation 1: Company and Users
Companies.findAll({ include: [ Users ] }).then((res) => console.log(res));
Users.findAll({ include: [ Companies ] }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

it gives me this error:

```
(node:4893) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: companies is not associated to users!
```

I've tried a couple of solutions online but it didn't help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`BelongsTo` means one to one relationship while a company may have multiple users (meaning, calling `BelongsTo` after `hasMany` collide!).

For more: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Comment: Thank you, When trying to solve above problem I also come across this article and apparently it didn't help. I'm trying to run this code 

Users.findAll({ include: [ Companies ] }).then((res) => console.log(res));

and to do that it appears to me that you have to specify a relationship between Users and Companies from Users side

Comment: @IngVankhinh right, it makes sense that a `User` will have a foreign-key into the `Companies` table

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help this community brother